# Fixing compiler error in GCC with header file

Tags: c, pointers, header-files

The explanation I've received in class for creating a header file was somewhat unclear. My professor said that creating a header file, you want to include the function prototypes. I keep getting errors with my function prototypes containing pointer tokens.
My header file:

```
#ifndef A3_H
#define A3_H

void list_init(record_list*);
void list_destroy(record_list*);
int  list_insert(record_list*, const record*);
int input_record(record*);

#endif
```

And the errors I'm receiving is:

```
$ gcc -ansi -W -Wall -pedantic -c a3.c
In file included from a3.c:4:0:
a3.h:4:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
a3.h:5:30: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
a3.h:6:29: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
a3.h:7:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

Am I not able to include pointers in function prototypes in a header file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have pointers in the header file, but it looks like you haven't defined `record` or `record_list` anywhere.

Comment: Those would be my structures, so those then need to also be defined in the header file?

Comment: @SpaceJesus A forward declaration is enough

Comment: You're welcome.  Proper maintenance of header files is important in your C projects.  You need to make sure that each header file is self-contained, and doesn't rely on other header files having been included before it.  If you need to have a given `.h` file to be included, such as to bring in `struct` definitions like your case, then your header file should explicitly include it.